# Why is IIS redirecting as if the default document isn't set?

Tags: asp.net, iis

This is a small thing but it is driving me crazy and I am hoping that an IIS expert can help.

The scenario is simple:

- IIS is configured so that "default.aspx" is the default document for
  a site.
- Forms authentication is on and the loginUrl is default.aspx
  and defaultURL is default.aspx
- In web.config, the default.aspx document has an authorization of ' * ' (anyone can access)

When I navigate to the site with just the base url: www.somesite.com the URL comes back with: www.somesite.com/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

If I navigate to the full name (www.somesite.com/default.aspx) it does not have the ReturnUrl.  So, why, when IIS adds the name, do we get the weird redirect but not when we type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `<allow users="?" />` to allow non-logged-in users too.

Comment: Yeah, you need * and ?, ? means unauthenticated and * means all authenticated